# How do I lag columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis, sliding-window

Consider the following table:

```
SELECT id, value FROM table ORDER BY id ASC;
+-----+---------+
| id  | value   |
+-----+---------+
| 12  | 158     |
| 15  | 346     |
| 27  | 334     |
| 84  | 378     |
| 85  | 546     |
+-----+---------+
```

The `id` column is auto-incremented but contains gaps. The `value` column is numeric.

I want to look at the increase in `value` over time by setting `value` in relation to the `value` two rows above. That is for row `id=85` I want to set the `value` of row `id=85` (546) in relation to the `value` of row `id=27` (334). The value to be computed for row `id=85` is hence 546/334=1.63473.

This is the result I want to achieve:

```
SELECT id, value, ...;
+-----+---------+---------------------+
| id  | value   | value/lag(value, 2) | (the syntax value/lag(value, 2) is made up)
+-----+---------+---------------------+
| 12  | 158     | NULL                |
| 15  | 346     | NULL                |
| 27  | 334     | 2.11392             | (334/158=2.11392)
| 84  | 378     | 1.09248             | (378/346=1.09248)
| 85  | 546     | 1.63473             | (546/334=1.63473)
+-----+---------+---------------------+
```

How do I perform such lagging in MySQL?

Please note that the `id` column contains gaps, so simply joining on the same table with `t1.id = t2.id - 2` will not work.

Comment: There is a lag() function in the SQL standard but MySQL does not support this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution that returns what you want in MySQL

```
SET @a :=0;
SET @b :=2;
SELECT r.id, r.value, r.value/r2.value AS 'lag'
FROM
(SELECT if(@a, @a:=@a+1, @a:=1) as rownum, id, value FROM results) AS r
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT if(@b, @b:=@b+1, @b:=1) as rownum, id, value FROM results) AS r2
ON r.rownum = r2.rownum
```

MySQL 5.1 doesn't like a self join against a subquery so you have to count rows twice, so not as tidy or scalable as it might be, but it does make specifying the lag simple.

For readers that use Oracle instead this is much easier

```
SELECT id, value, value/lag(value, 2) over (order by id) as lag from results;
```

Comment: *For readers that use Oracle*: or PostgreSQL or DB2 or Teradata :)

Answer (score 0):

As there are only two rows between the current one and the one from where you want to get the 'historical' data could you perphaps use variables to store the data temporarily using something like:

`set @oldid0=999999;

set @oldid1=999999;

set @oldid2=999999;

select @oldid0:=@oldid1,@oldid1:=@oldid2,@oldid2:=id, value/@oldid0 from table order by id asc;`

It is a very untidy solution but I think it will do the job. Maybe there is some way of preventing the variables from being displayed, I've not looked into it that far.

Comment: Lag(2) is just an example. I'm looking for a general solution that would allow for say Lag(365) :-)

Comment: Ah, I read your question and stupidly assumed that you only meant lag(2)