# how to do lag operation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Guys I want to use analytical function lag in mysql. In Oracle it is supported but I can't do it in Mysql. So can anybody help me how to perform lag operation in Mysql?
For example

```
UID                        Operation
 1                         Logged-in
 2                         View content
 3                         Review
```

I want to use lag function so that my output would be as follows

```
UID                        Operation              Lagoperation
 1                         Logged-in                
 2                         View content           Logged-in
 3                         Review                 View content
```

Does Mysql support lag function???

Comment: I think there's no built-in function. You would probably have to JOIN same table in order get such effect. Try something from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483319/how-do-i-lag-columns-in-mysql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql

Comment: No, MySQL does not support any of the modern SQL features (window functions, recursive queries, ...). If that is really important for you, you might consider upgrading to Postgres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can emulate it with user variables:

```
select uid, operation, previous_operation from (
select
y.*
, @prev AS previous_Operation
, @prev := Operation
from
your_table y
, (select @prev:=NULL) vars
order by uid
) subquery_alias
```

- see it working in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d1aa/3/0) live

Here you initialize your variable(s). It's the same as writing `SET @prev:=NULL;` before writing your query.

```
, (select @prev:=NULL) vars
```

Then the order of these statements in the select clause is important:

```
, @prev AS previous_Operation
, @prev := Operation
```

The first just displays the variables value, the second assigns the value of the current row to the variable.

It's also important to have an `ORDER BY` clause, as the output is otherwise not deterministic.

All this is put into a subquery just out of aesthetic reasons,... to filter out this

```
, @prev := Operation
```

column.