# select when record change value

Tags: mysql, select, triggers

I'm trying to select just records which changed values compared to previous record,

my table is looking like this

```
Id(int) | value(boolean) |
-------------------------
1       | 0              |
-------------------------
2       | 1              |
-------------------------
3       | 1              |
-------------------------
4       | 1              |
-------------------------
5       | 0              |
-------------------------
6       | 0              |
-------------------------
```

I must get id:2,5

thanks for your help

Comment: Go on - try something, anything. And is id always incremental

Answer (score 1):

I did a self-join, but instead of joining identical `id`s, I join `t1.id = t2.id-1` and then compare the values:

```
select t2.id 
from thetable t1
inner join thetable t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1
where t1.value != t2.value
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d626/4

Edit to add:
Thanks to @Ravinder, I figured out a way to do this even if the ids aren't sequential.
I used [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483319/how-do-i-lag-columns-in-mysql).

```
SET @a :=0;
SET @b :=1;
SELECT t1.id, t1.rownum
FROM
(SELECT if(@a, @a:=@a+1, @a:=1) as rownum, id, value FROM thetable) AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT if(@b, @b:=@b+1, @b:=1) as rownum, id, value FROM thetable) AS t2
ON t1.rownum = t2.rownum
where t2.value != t1.value
```

[SQLFiddle with non-sequential ids](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c4c5b/23)

Basically if you don't have sequential ids you create your own. I called them rownum.

Comment: Idea is good. Let us hope id is stored sequential and no records in between are deleted or altered.

Comment: @Ravinder it would still work in this case, assuming the desired functionality was to only show changes between sequential ids: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c4c5b/1  ...but if asker wanted difference to return 9 in my example... not so much.

Comment: @Ravinder, I came up with a solution for non-sequential case as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql variable in query to check if its new or unchanged

```
SELECT
`Id`, 
`value`,
(CASE when @test=value then 'unchanged'
else 'changed' end) occurance,
@test:=`value`  testvar
FROM
  Table1 
,(SELECT @test:='new') t
HAVING occurance='changed'
ORDER BY `Id`
```

### [See fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3304/9)

Comment: This should really have an ORDER BY clause.