# get the different value from sql

Tags: php, mysql, diff

i have the following table

```
id   rack        usage    day
1    rack1       100      20141210
2    rack1       120      20141211
3    rack1       135      20141212  
4    rack1       144      20141213
5    rack1       160      20141214
6    rack1       165      20141215
7    rack1       167      20141216
```

i would like to get the diffrent of the usage per day. how to acomplish with select query? so it will result

```
day       usage
20141210  0
20141211  20
20141212  15
20141213  9
20141214  16
20141215  5
20141216  3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I lag columns in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483319/how-do-i-lag-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, it should work :

```
select day, usage, id as id_rack,
usage - (select usage from my_table t where t.id < id_rack order by t.id desc limit 1) as usage
from my_table
```

Comment: What do you mean by "diffrent" !!

Comment: @lainard I think you mean *difference* of usage between each day?

Comment: Yes the date is on the row day not date

Comment: You mean average of use per day? if so then try : 

SELECT day, avg(usage) as usage
FROM my_table
GROUP BY day

Comment: No but the diffrential each day, i have change the table above to make it easier to understand

Comment: select day, usage, id as id_rack,
usage - (select usage from my_table t where t.id < id_rack order by t.id desc limit 1) as usage
from my_table

Comment: @Simo Thank you but unfortunetly it gives me error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usage, id as id_rack, usage - (select usage from my_table t where t.id < id_rack' at line 1

Comment: @Simo Thank you this is actually what i need. awsome  sorry above comment cant be edited

Comment: Glad that I could help ^^

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT day, sum(usage) as usage FROM tbl_name GROUP BY day;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RandomSeed even if this were incorrect, they've still attempted to solve the question. I would consider this an answer.

Comment: I have simplied the table to make it undestandable i would like to get the difference of the usage each day

Answer (score 0):

select t1.day as day, (t2.usage-t1.usage) as usage from table t1, table t2 where date_format(date_add(t1.date, interval 1 day),'%Y%m%d')=t2.date;

Check this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT l.day,l.usage -
                    (SELECT x.usage 
                    FROM testing x
                    WHERE x.rackid < l.rackid
                    ORDER BY rackid DESC
                    LIMIT 1)
FROM testing l
```

Comment: thanks Jivani closer to the what i need but not the correct one