# MySQL Grouping Under 30s Separation Possible?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains user actions over a given day for all my users. I am trying to construct sessions for these users from this data. My algorithm says "if a user has not made an action for 30s, the session has finished". I have my data in the format of:

User_id | Action | Timestamp

I'm wondering if its possible to use SQL to output the sessions by grouping wherever there is less than a 30s gap between actions carried out by the same user?

Comment: You could add a field in your query that would be something like `if(gap > 30, 'Y', 'N') as myField` and group on that field

Comment: how would this be applied on a per row basis? ie as it goes through the data it only triggers when the current row is more than 30s after the previous row?

Comment: LAG functions support this.  see this answer for MySQL  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql

Comment: My apologies, I misread your question. I believe this post will answer your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483319/how-do-i-lag-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: This looks good, I've implemented it with my `timestamp` column, however it appears to just be giving me years. I have the following query:

`SET @quot=-1;
select mongoid,@quot lag_timestamp, @quot:=timestamp curr_timestamp
  from datas order by mongoid,timestamp`

But the `lag_timestamp` column is always just a year